# Change values in PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of users and page change information with input boxes is the old value
And click on send it needs to change the values.
It does nothing
(Sorry for my english)

this is editInfo.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasse");

if(!$connect) { die("החיבור כשל"); }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `Username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'; ");

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $ID = $info["ID"];
        printf("
        <form action='editInfo.php' method='post'>
        שם משתמש: <input type='username' name='username' value='%s'/> <br>
        סיסמה חדשה: <input type='password' name='password' value=''/> <br>
        שם: <input type='text' name='name' value='%s'/> <br>
        אימייל: <input type='email' name='email' value='%s'/> <br>
        <input type='submit' name='change' value='עדכן' />
        </form>", $info["Username"], $info["Name"], $info["Email"]);

    $newUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $newPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $newName = $_POST['name'];
    $newEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $chagne = $_POST['change'];

    if(isset($change)) {
        $changeCode = "UPDATE `users`.`user` SET `Name` = '$newName', `Username` = '$newUsername', `Password` = '$newPassword', `Email` = '$newEmail' WHERE `user`.`Username` = '".$info["username"]."';";

        $changeQuery = mysql_query($changeCode);
        $runIt = mysql_num_rows($changeQuery);

        if(!$runIt) {
            echo 'לא הצלחנו לשנות את הפרטים';
        }
        else {
            echo 'פרטים עודכנו בהצלחה';
        }
    }
    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: I realize there's a language barrier here, but it's very difficult to understand what you're asking.  Can you clarify?  Also, be aware that this code is filled with SQL injection vulnerabilities.  You should fix that.

Comment: First off, I know that the code is immune from sql injection I guard it at the end.

I want the page to print the user is connected to the information he wrote register and he can edit them and it will be updated in a database

Comment: No, this code is ***not*** immune from SQL injection.  This code is, in multiple separate ways, *very* vulnerable to SQL injection.  Additionally, you're storing user passwords in plain text.  Which is *grossly irresponsible*.  Please learn what SQL injection is so you can protect your code from it.  And please stop harvesting people's passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.  First you set one variable:

```
$chagne = $_POST['change'];
```

Then you check for another variable:

```
if(isset($change)) {
```

In this code, `$change` will never be set.  So that `if` statement will always be false.

---

Also, please be aware that your code is ***highly vulnerable to SQL injection***.  Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) to learn what that means.  But the bottom line is that you're currently *executing user input as code* which allows any user to execute any code on your database.  A significant step in the right direction would be to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of string concatenation to build your queries.

Also, you are storing user passwords in plain text.  This is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.  You are basically harvesting people's passwords and storing them in a highly insecure database.  Please learn how to hash passwords properly so they can't be retrieved.

Comment: @SELECT: if this answers your question, please accept it. To do so, find the 'tick' mark to the left of it and click it, so it turns green. This is our way of marking a question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You variable:

```
 $chagne = $_POST['change'];
```

Replace $chagne with $change

and your if:

```
 if(isset($change)) {
```

Try and be more carefull at your variable names.